# ffmpegX extract frames from video

Tags: ffmpeg, extract, frames

I found this tutorial:

http://stream0.org/2008/02/howto-extract-images-from-a-vi.html

Where it tells me how to extract frames from a video with ffmpegX from the commandline (at least that is what I understood).

I cd in the directory where the .MOV files is I want to extract and ran in the Mac OS Terminal(!):

```
ffmpeg -i mymov.MOV -r 25 -f image2 images%05d.png
```

and

```
ffmpegX -i mymov.MOV -r 25 -f image2 images%05d.png
```

But on both I get:

-bash: ffmpegX: command not found

All this on a Mac.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install ffmpeg : http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: So ffmpeg and ffmpegX is not identical?