# How to create thumb image while uploading video

Tags: php, file-upload, thumbnails

How to a create thumb image while uploading a video, am using the following code

```
if ((!empty($vdo))) {
    $ext1 = explode('.', $_FILES['tut_video']['name']);
    $vname = "T_" . $ext1['0'] . '.' . $ext1['1'];
    $vdo_name1 = "../images/tut_vid/" . basename($vname);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tut_video']['tmp_name'], $vdo_name1);
    $vdo_name1c = "../images/tut_vid/" . basename($vname);
    $vdopath_old1 = "../" . $vdo_name1;
}
```

please help..

Comment: which video is this ? I think you need to use some Video library package to extract the images from video. Try using ffmpeg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983327/ffmpegx-extract-frames-from-video

Comment: Nice searching... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053048/need-to-create-thumbnail-for-video-uploading-very-simple-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some tool like ffmpeg for creating thumb images from a video, use :

ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240

( http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/ )

Comment: how to do it dynamically in server side

Comment: http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/06/22/create-a-random-thumbnail-of-a-video-file/ ... found this

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the platform you're on, but on linux the answer usually revolves around ffmpeg:

- [Tutorial 1](http://drupal.org/node/358221)
- [Tutorial 2](http://echophp-mysql.blogspot.com/2010/12/ffmpeg.html)
- [Tutorial 3](http://www.alberton.info/video_preview_as_animated_gif_with_ffmpeg_and_spl.html)
- [Stackoverflow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264840/thumbnail-of-video-in-php-while-uploading)
- [Stackoverflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053048/need-to-create-thumbnail-for-video-uploading-very-simple-code)
- [Stackoverflow question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265572/how-to-create-thumbnails-or-preview-for-videos)

Btw, your extension checking does not handle well files with multiple dots in them. This does:

```
$in_filename = $_FILES['tut_video']['name'];

$pos = strrpos($in_filename, '.');

$ext1 = '';
if ($pos !== false) {
  $ext1 = substr($in_filename, $pos + 1);
}
```